# use the Parameterization in u and v to write the term $x^2+y^2$

Tags: parametric

Given that :

$u=xy$

$v=x^2-y^2$

we want to write the term $x^2+y^2 $ using only $u$ and $v$.

how can we do this ?

**update:** please reread my question I have edited it. I think it is clear now sorry for misconception

Comment: Your question is out of context.  Computing a line integral along what curve?

Comment: It does not matter ... I'll edit it

Comment: edited you can check it up now

Comment: Oh, I see.  So it's really just an algebra question.

Comment: yes I have to use to solve a calculus question :)

Comment: if someone voted down please reread my question I think I have wrote it clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u = xy$, $v = x^2 - y^2$

Then $$x^2 = \frac{u^2}{y^2} = v + y^2$$, so $$y^4 + vy^2 - u^2 = 0$$

Let $z = y^2$, then
$$z^2 + vz - u^2 = 0 \implies y^2 = z = \frac{-v \pm \sqrt{v^2 - 4u^2}}{2}$$

Similarly, 
$$y^2 = \frac{u^2}{x^2} = x^2 - v$$ so $$x^4 - vx^2 - u^2 = 0$$
Let $w = x^2$, then 
$$x^4 - vx^2 - u^2 = 0 \implies x^2 = w = \frac{v \pm \sqrt{v^2 + 4u^2}}{2}$$

So $$x^2 + y^2 = \frac12(\pm \sqrt{v^2 - 4u^2} \pm \sqrt{v^2 + 4u^2})$$

I think I may have added some extraneous solutions. Either that or there is no convenient singular solution. Of course, the sign of $v^2 - 4u^2$ needs to be taken into account.

Comment: I see you made an important progress so we just need to determine the right signs.
I think we need to take positive/negative Considerations on the equations you wrote to determine the right signs. 
do you think so ?

Comment: Yeah, since $x^2,y^2 > 0$, $v \pm \sqrt{v^2 + 4u^2} > 0$, $-v \pm \sqrt{v^2 - 4u^2} > 0$. As well as the contents of the radicals.